# how to remove special char from the string and make new string?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a string `4(4X),4(4N),3(3X)` from this string I want to make string `4,4,3`. If I am getting the string `4(4N),3(3A),2(2X)` then I want to make my string `4,3,2`.

Please someone tell me how can I solve my problem.

Comment: What if string is `4(4), 3(42), 2(x)`?

Comment: I split the string and used .Remove for removing the special char., but not getting proper string

Comment: I am not creating the string like this 4(4), 3(42), 2(x), always i'll get string as I have shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Linq query selects substring from each part of input string, starting from beginning till first open brace:

```
string input = "4(4N),3(3A),2(2X)";
string result = String.Join(",", input.Split(',')
                                  .Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('('))));
// 4,3,2
```

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad thanks! well, maybe not better, but more compact :)

Comment: Thanks all, I used @lazyberezovsky example its working well for me

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
string inputString = "4(4X),4(4N),3(3X)";
string[] temp = inputString.Split(',');
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in temp)
{
    result.Add(item.Split('(')[0]);
}

var whatYouNeed = string.Join(",", result);
```

Comment: I think you will get an error at this part `var whatYouNeed = string.Join(",", result);`

Comment: yeah, i tried, It has no error! I thought it will get an error because `String.Join(**String Separator**, **String[] Value**);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
String input = @"4(4X),4(4N),3(3X)";
String pattern = @"(\d)\(\1.\)";
// ( ) - first group.
// \d - one number
// \( and \) - braces.
// \1 - means the repeat of first group.
String result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1");
// $1 means, that founded patterns will be replcaed by first group
//result = 4,4,3
```